# Where can I find compojure.html?

Tags: html, clojure, compojure

I justed started experimenting with compojure and I'd like to create HTML output with the syntax I've found in several compojure examples:

```
(html [:html
        [:head
          [:title "Page title"]]
...
```

But I'm using compojure 0.6.2 and it seems like this syntax isn't included in compojure core.

How can I include it in my project?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
(ns your-namespace
  (:require hiccup.core))
```

Answer (score 2):

That's a feature of [Hiccup](https://github.com/weavejester/hiccup), not Compojure.

Answer (score 1):

While your primary question has been answered, I would also look at other options just to fully learn what you have available for html generation tools. For example I prefer [Enlive](https://github.com/cgrand/enlive/wiki/getting-started)

Not to say either is automatically better than the other, but more options is better.